# Understanding how to test RxJava Observables

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am learning how to write android unit tests. And, I am looking at examples: So, I saw something like this:

```
@Test
public void getPopularMoviesMakesApiCall() {
    // given that the api service returns a response
    1. when(apiService.discover(SORT_BY_POPULARITY, PAGE, API_KEY)).thenReturn(Observable.just(mDiscoverMoviesResponse));

    // when getPopularMovies is invoked
    2. mRemoteRepository.getPopularMovies(1).subscribeWith(mMovieListTestSubscriber);

    // then, verify that the api request is made and returns the expected response
    3. verify(apiService).discover(SORT_BY_POPULARITY, PAGE, API_KEY);
    4. mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertValue(mMovieList);
}
```

I tried to run it, and I noticed option 1 executes always, option 2 does too. But, if option 3 doesn't comform with the information in option 2,
it throws an error saying they aren't the same. Which means option 3 confirms option 2. If I'm wrong or there's anything to correct, please 
do tell. So, I wrote something like this:

```
@Test
public void testBadHashException() throws Exception {

  1. mRemoteRepository.getPopularMovies(1, FAKE_API_KEY).subscribeWith(mMovieListTestSubscriber);

  2. mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertNoValues();
  3. mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertError(HttpException.class);
}
```

This is what I noticed:

```
private List<Movie> mMovieList;
private DiscoverMoviesResponse mDiscoverMoviesResponse;

private MoviesRepository mRemoteRepository;

private TestObserver<List<Movie>> mMovieListTestSubscriber;
private TestObserver<Movie> mMovieTestSubscriber;

@Mock
MovieApiService apiService;
```

Those above, were declared at the top, and initialized by a `Mockito @Before @annotation` like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mRemoteRepository = new MoviesRemoteRepository(apiService);

    mMovieTestSubscriber = new TestObserver<>();
    mMovieListTestSubscriber = new TestObserver<>();

    mMovieList = TestDataGenerator.generateMovieList(10);
    mDiscoverMoviesResponse = TestDataGenerator.generateDiscoverMoviesResponse(mMovieList);
}
```

Note: TestDataGenerator is a helper class for generating data. As it's done there, he got MovieList and then got another which is the main response body.

APIService: The retrofit service class.
MoviesRepository: An helper class for manipulating Observables in the service class. Which is used by the ViewModel.

The second test keeps giving me `java.lang.RuntimeException: No mock defined for invocation`. I don't seem to understand it yet. 
Is there a specific instance where I should use when, verify, how do I test for Observable Retrofit Request Errors.

If it's saying no Mock data, but then Mock data has been generated when this is done. Or is it supposed to be mocked differently?

`mMovieList = TestDataGenerator.generateMovieList(10);
mDiscoverMoviesResponse = TestDataGenerator.generateDiscoverMoviesResponse(mMovieList);`

More on my observation:

I was going through `Mockito` and I noticed, the first test that went through was executing because he did:

`1. when(apiService.discover(SORT_BY_POPULARITY, PAGE, API_KEY)).thenReturn(Observable.just(mDiscoverMoviesResponse));`

Since the error for the second function shows `java.lang.RuntimeException: No mock defined for invocation`, it was stated that the method
within a class can be mocked by using `when("some method").thenReturn()` it's okay. I then modified my `testBadHashException` to look like this:

```
@Test
public void testBadHashException() throws Exception {

  0. when(apiService.discover(SORT_BY_POPULARITY, PAGE, API_KEY)).thenReturn(Observable.just(mDiscoverMoviesResponse));

  1. mRemoteRepository.getPopularMovies(1, FAKE_API_KEY).subscribeWith(mMovieListTestSubscriber);

  2. mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertNoValues();
  3. mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertError(HttpException.class);
}
```

Instead of it throwing an exception, it threw a success.

I rewrote the error test:

```
@Test
public void getPopularMoviesThrowsError() {
    when(mMoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(PAGE)).thenReturn(Observable.<List<Movie>>error(new TimeoutException()));

    // request movies
    mMoviesViewModel.discoverMovies(true);

    verify(mMoviesRepository).getPopularMovies(PAGE);

    // check that empty view is hidden
    assertFalse(mMoviesViewModel.emptyViewShowing.get());

    // check that loading view is hidden
    assertFalse(mMoviesViewModel.moviesLoading.get());

    // check that error view is showing
    assertTrue(mMoviesViewModel.errorViewShowing.get());
}
```

There is a compilation error here: `when(mMoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(PAGE)).thenReturn(Observable.<List<Movie>>error(new TimeoutException()));`

It cannot resolve method here: `Observable.<List<Movie>>error(new TimeoutException())`

Writing tests in Android looks really weird compared to JavaScript. Any help on how I can learn or achieve understanding how to write unit testing would be appreciated. I just adopted
the MVVM pattern and I'm trying to write test with it. Thanks.

Comment: When you call getPopularMovies(1, FAKE_API_KEY) which method of your apiService is going to be called? Did you mocked this method using mockito??

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I updated my question

Comment: What is throwing success? The test or the getPopularMovies Observable? I am not sure what you are trying to do... Do you need the apiService to return a Observable that throws an exception? You need to change the Observable to throw the exception you need

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira I kind of understand when it says the Mock is null. The functions in the interface service class is null. That's the essence of `when(apiService.discover(SORT_BY_POPULARITY, PAGE, API_KEY))`. I want to test for error, so I did something like this: (Please check the updated question)

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira If I change the Observable to throw an error, are you saying I should change the Object `APIService` Observable function is emitting?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send an error to your Observable you can create it like this:

```
when(mMoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(PAGE)).thenReturn(  
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<SomeClass>() { 
        @Override public void call(Subscriber<SomeCladd> subscriber) {
          subscriber.onError(new Exception("some message!")); 
         } 
        }));
```

This way you will have a Observable that returns an error so you can call

mMovieListTestSubscriber.assertError

The problem that you are having is that you using Observable.just to create your Observable... So the method onError is never going to be called, just the onNext.